# Can I launch Huawei Map SDK on non-Huawei device?

Tags: android, flutter, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-map-kit

I don't have possibility right now to test my app on Huawei device so I tried to do it on Android Studio emulator but I am getting this error and I don't know it's because it is not Huawei device or it is something else?

`Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: com.huawei.hms.flutter.map/map`

Answer (score 2):

This error seems like flutter plugin loading problem.
You need to follow the guide to check the configuration in your project:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/integrating-sdk-0000001050188606

If you want to use Map on non-Huawei device, you need to add the following dependency in build.gradle file in "huawei-map plugin"(Please use the latest plugin):

```
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps-basic:6.4.1.300'
```

like below:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps:6.4.1.300'
    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps-basic:6.4.1.300'

    implementation 'androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0' }
```